# Sitecore 7.2 DMS get traffic name by traffic ID

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I'm struggling to get traffic type name from Sitecore DMS analytics tracker by traffic ID. Is there a way to do this?

I get the ID:

```csharp
int id = Tracker.CurrentVisit.TrafficType
```

Then I was trying to play with

```csharp
Tracker.SharedData.TrafficTypes
```

to find traffic name but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nowhere that stores a "traffic type name". I think the best you can do is look here:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Traffic Type`

Find the Traffic Type item with the `Value` field that matches the one you're looking for and use the name or display name of the item.

Alternatively you could create your own custom mapping items.

Comment: This is what I ended up with. I'll accept this as an answer if nobody comes up with a solution which finds traffic name via Analytics API. Thank you